# Grabbing User Tweets using IDs in Python

Tags: python, twitter

I am working in Python. I retrieved 20 random user IDs from a user's follower's list. I would now like to extract tweets from the random accounts . I want to extract their tweets from 10 specific time frames, each time frame is one week long. Any suggestions for how to do this?

This is what I have so far.

```
import random
rndm_flwr_ids = random.sample(ids, 20)

print rndm_flwr_ids
[3313501976, 2546815928, 388567020, 3949321577, 3168108935, 47848135, 22993942, 822041650365165568, 4836791590, 1938150769, 3885750083, 754472175642419200, 829673667483295749, 2812463408, 3300923289, 3004536700, 738435174472392704, 30958980, 763437360654811136, 161446209]

tweets_by_flwr = {}
for follower in rndm_flwr_ids:
 tweets_by_flwr[follower] = api.user_timeline(follower, page = page)
```

Then I got an error: TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 503

Here is the total response I've gotten after trying a couple of hours apart. I got the 503 error last week too--

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TweepError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-93f45edd91ea> in <module>()
      2 
      3 for follower in rndm_flwr_ids:
----> 4      tweets_by_flwr[follower] = api.user_timeline(follower, page = page)

C:\Users\kcavanagh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.pyc in _call(*args, **kwargs)
    243             return method
    244         else:
--> 245             return method.execute()
    246 
    247     # Set pagination mode

C:\Users\kcavanagh\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.pyc in execute(self)
    227                     raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
    228                 else:
--> 229                     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
    230 
    231             # Parse the response payload

TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 503
```

Comment: This is an error message from Twitter, meaning their servers are overworked right now, [source](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes)

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it a couple times in between...still getting 503. I put the total error response in my original question.

Comment: So does that happen right away or does the script run for a while? Does it pull something? The error  msg doesn't really tell me much.

Comment: The script runs for a while but it does not pull anything. The error message is the only thing that comes up. (sorry if I'm not using the right vocabulary, I am new to Python)

Comment: is the above code all you have? or where do you tell the script to save/ output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you checked but this https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes clearly explains why you are having that error code! you should give it some time and try again!

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it a couple times in between...still getting 503. I put the total error response in my original question.